# Is this Bayesian Network Probability calculation correct?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I think I understand how to calculate BN and why it is so, but complex net still confuses me. Currently how I understand it is that, if there is any 'result' variable in the probability, it can be calculated by converting it to `P(result|cause)P(cause)`. So I assumed in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzd8I.png) bayesian network (A,B → C → D,E), if you want to get `P(B,E)`, every parent and grand parent of `B` and `E` should be considered. As `B` doesn't have parent, only the (grand) parent of `E` (`A,C`) will hop in, and finally it can be calculated as :

P(B,E)
= P(B,E,**A,C**)+P(B,E,**~A,C**)+P(B,E,**A,~C**)+P(B,E,**~A,~C**)

The joint probability would be :

P(B,E,A,C) = P(B)P(A)P(C|A,B)P(E|C)

The rest of them are calculated the same way. I'd like to check if this calculation and my understanding is right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the DAG: $$\begin{array}{ccc}A&&&&B\\&\searrow&&\swarrow \\&&C\\&\swarrow&&\searrow\\D&&&&E\end{array}$$

Then, yes,$$P_{B,E}=\sum_{A,C}P_AP_BP_{C\mid A, B}P_{E\mid C}$$